# dynamic method binding in python

Tags: python, polymorphism

I have the following two classes A and B. How do I make the do_someting() method call the overriden method, some_method(), in B. Is this doable in Python?

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def some_method()
        # pass
        return

    @classmethod
    def do_something():
        A.some_method()
        ...
        return

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def some_method()
        # how does do_something call here?
        return

    @classmethod
    def run()
        B.do_something()
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just make sure to fix your colons pass in `self` and `cls`:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def some_method():
        # pass
        return

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        cls.some_method()
        return

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def some_method():
        print("I did stuff!")
        return

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        B.do_something()
        return

k = B()
k.run()
>>>"I did stuff!"
```

And if you want to call the old `do_something` (the one in class A) from class B, just pass in the appropriate class. In class B:

```
@classmethod
def run(cls):
    A.do_something()
    return
```